# R: head/tail on stringsplit

Tags: r, strsplit

I need to rephrase my question, because i didn´t include other kinds of data in my data frame which cause a lot of problems when splitting by blanks. I´m really sorry!

Important: blanks cannot be trusted all over the dataset, because they appear in an erratic manner, even within the same type of date (type1a, type1b in my example)

```
df <- data.table(v=c( "       555 OUT XYZ STR44W PASSED TRUE",   #interesting data type1
                      "       A 45 OUT XYW STR44W PASSED TRUE",
                      "       555 OUT XYZ STR55W PASSED TRUE",
                      "       6755 OUT XYZ 4444W PASSED TRUE",
                      "  75/850CC/PF                         ",   #eratic data to be ignored
                      " BY HHU 56TT00 6 415 UP HHU 88H900   ",   #interesting data type2
                      "       555 OUT WWWZ STR44W PASSED TRUE"))
```

desired outcome:

```
T1  T2  T1_V1   T1_V2   T1_V3   T2_V1   T2_V2   T2_V3   T2_V4 T2_V5
1   0   555     XYZ     STR44W  NA      NA      NA      NA    NA
1   0   A 45    XYW     STR44W  NA      NA      NA      NA    NA
1   0   555     XYZ     STR55W  NA      NA      NA      NA    NA
1   0   6755    XYZ     4444W   NA      NA      NA      NA    NA
0   0   NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA    NA
0   1   NA      NA      NA      HHU     56TT00  6 415   HHU   88H900
1   0   555     NA      STR44W  NA      NA      NA      NA    NA
```

Solution by now for type1 data:
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(v=c( "       555 OUT XYZ STR44W PASSED TRUE", #Type1a
                      "       A 45 OUT XYW STR44W PASSED TRUE", #Type1b
                      "       555 OUT XYZ STR55W PASSED TRUE", #Type1a
                      "       6755 OUT XYZ 4444W PASSED TRUE",  #Type1a
                      "  75/850CC/PF                         ",   #!!new line of eratic data
                      " BY HHU 56TT00 6 415 UP HHU 88H900   ",   #Type2
                      "       555 OUT WWWZ STR44W PASSED TRUE" )) #Type1a

```
df$T1<-0
df$T1[grepl("PASSED TRUE", df$v)]<-1
df$T1_V1[df$T1==1]<-df$T1_V1
df$T1_V1[df$T1==1] <-gsub("\\OUT.*","",df$v) #Getting rid of the everything after "OUT"
df$T1_V2[df$T1==1]<-gsub(".*\\OUT","",df$v)#Getting rid of the everything before "OUT"
df$T1_V2 <-gsub("\\PASSED.*","",df$T1_V2) #Getting rid of the everything after "PASSED"
df$T1_V2<-strsplit(df$T1_V2, "[[:blank:]*]") # Seperation of the two relevant strings by stringsplit
df$T1_V2<- lapply(df$T1_V2, head)
```

## Problem: stringplit allows for selecting the right block after single out eratic datastructures with more blanks

## -> gsub the string down is extra effort, but with some of the data it was the only way to ensure that erratic blanks don´t mess up the variables

## -> how to convert  df$T1_V2  back to normal character variable with no blanks in it?

Old question:

First post, i tried my very best to find answers and to prepare my question.

I need to clean up a nasty string with a lot of spaces an irregularities. I try to get the first block before "OUT" and the second and third block between "OUT" and "PASSED". Afterwards the data should be checked with a list to control if v4 is correct.

Using stringsplit and afterwars head/tail doesn´t work and i would appreciate any help with that a lot! Many thanks in advance

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(v=c("       555 OUT XYZ STR44W PASSED TRUE",
                                  "       A 45 OUT XYW STR44W PASSED TRUE",
                                  "       555 OUT XYZ STR55W PASSED TRUE",
                                  "       6755 OUT XYZ 4444W PASSED TRUE",
                                  "       555 OUT WWWZ STR44W PASSED TRUE"))
control <-data.table(control=c("XYZ","PPO","XMX","WWWZ"))

df$v1 <-gsub("\\OUT.*","",df$v) #Getting rid of the everything after "OUT"
df$v2<-gsub(".*\\OUT","",df$v) #Getting rid of the everything before "OUT"
df$v2 <-gsub("\\PASSED.*","",df$v2) #Getting rid of the everything after "PASSED"
df$v2<-strsplit(df$v2, "[[:blank:]*]") # Seperation of the two relevant strings by stringsplit
df$v3<- lapply(df$v2, head) #Taking the first element from the stringsplit 
df$v4<- lapply(df$v2, head,2) #Taking the second element from the stringsplit
```

After running that, in r-studio i get c("", "XYZ") for v4. The first element appears to be an empty element? I wasn´t able to go on with that expression by controlling directly from my control list (fail1) nor by converting (fail2) nor by unlist (fail3)

```
#fail#1
df$v4[!(df$v4 %in% control$control)] <- NA

#fail#2
df$v4 <- as.character(df$v4)

#fail3
df$v4 <- unlist(df$v4)
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for your current data to get it into a tidier form.

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(v=c("       555 OUT XYZ STR44W PASSED TRUE",
                                  "       A 45 OUT XYW STR44W PASSED TRUE",
                                  "       555 OUT XYZ STR55W PASSED TRUE",
                                  "       6755 OUT XYZ 4444W PASSED TRUE",
                                  "       555 OUT WWWZ STR44W PASSED TRUE"))
control <-data.table(control=c("XYZ","PPO","XMX","WWWZ"))

df$v1 <-gsub("\\OUT.*","",df$v) #Getting rid of the everything after "OUT"
df$v2<-gsub(".*\\OUT","",df$v) #Getting rid of the everything before "OUT"
```

trim the whitespace and split it out by spaces, then cbind it to the current df. we can then rename the columns so it's a bit easier to navigate.

```
lists <- strsplit(trimws(df$v2), " ")
extra <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lists))
newdf <- cbind(df, extra)
colnames(newdf) <- c("full string", paste0("piece_", 1:6))

newdf
                              full string      piece_1                  piece_2 piece_3 piece_4 piece_5 piece_6
1:         555 OUT XYZ STR44W PASSED TRUE         555    XYZ STR44W PASSED TRUE     XYZ  STR44W  PASSED    TRUE
2:        A 45 OUT XYW STR44W PASSED TRUE        A 45    XYW STR44W PASSED TRUE     XYW  STR44W  PASSED    TRUE
3:         555 OUT XYZ STR55W PASSED TRUE         555    XYZ STR55W PASSED TRUE     XYZ  STR55W  PASSED    TRUE
4:         6755 OUT XYZ 4444W PASSED TRUE        6755     XYZ 4444W PASSED TRUE     XYZ   4444W  PASSED    TRUE
5:        555 OUT WWWZ STR44W PASSED TRUE         555   WWWZ STR44W PASSED TRUE    WWWZ  STR44W  PASSED    TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not completely understand what your end result requirement is. You do not need to use `gsub` at every step. You can split everything by `space`, and select the columns you would need to work further.

```
library(tidyr)
library(splitstackshape) # cSplit function    

df_selected <- df %>% cSplit("v", " ") %>% select(v_1,v_3,v_4,v_6)

control <-data.table(control=c("XYZ","PPO","XMX","WWWZ"))
filter(df_selected, v_3 %in% control$control)
```